# My ex came in the house, unplugged the garage door opener and jammed the doorknob of the door into the garage. How do i get the garage door open

Tags: doors, garage

My ex came into the house and disabled the garage door.   How do I get it open from the outside

Comment: Off topic comment here but.....Sounds like you really need to get the other entry locks changed as part of the recovery here.

Comment: If there's glass in the upper section of the garage door, you could smash it and pull the track release strap. Some garage doors also have a small keyed release on the outside to allow you to do this without the smashing.

Comment: With just a coat hanger: http://www.itstactical.com/intellicom/physical-security/safety-announcement-protecting-against-garage-door-break-ins/

Comment: You need a locksmith.

Answer (score 2):

Virtually all doors that are between the house and garage open into the house. This means that the hinges are visible from the house side. One alternative is to remove the hinge pins and the door should be able to be pulled inwards toward the house. Modern doors of this type will be a fire break type of door and may be fairly heavy so get assistance if needed to handle moving the thing.

Now you can then figure out the door knob issue from both sides now. If the knob has been broken to the state of non-usability you can replace it at fairly low cost. If necessary there are semi-destructive ways to cut off and removing a broken knob if it has been damaged beyond normal removal methods.

Do yourself a huge favor and get the other entry door locks re-keyed or replaced as soon as possible to prevent access by unauthorized persons that may have copies of the original keys.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't said how he jammed the door from the house into the garage and what kind of lock you have.

You should be able to remove the locking mechanism of the door from the house into the garage. On our door the deadbolt has two screws which if removed allow the dead bolt toggle to be removed and then the other side mechanism could be pushed out into the garage.

Our pass lock handle has an allen screw that allows the handle to be removed and then the metal bezel pops off revealing screws which hold the inside mechanism in place.

A locksmith will be able to resolve this quickly.

It goes without saying that what this person did to these doors is breaking the law.

Comment: He somehow jammed the knob. It won't turn to allow the door to open

Comment: How do you know he was breaking the law, maybe he owns the stuff. And why did you immediately assume it was a "he"?

Comment: Damaging property and causing a safety hazard to inconvenience and harass a former domestic partner has got to be a violation of some law.